# find index of similar values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array that looks like this

```
a   b

1   1
1   1
1   1
1   2
1   3
1   3
2   24
3   1
3   1
3   1
3   1
4   5
4   5
4   7
4   9
```

Is it possible to get indices of all values of a where values of b are equal? (I dont want indices where a = b, I want indices for all 'a' where 'b' are equal )

for example for a = 1 and b = 1, it should just return me [0,1,2], 
for a = 1 and b =2 , return [3]
for a = 1 and b =3, return [4, 5] 
and for a=2 and b=24, it should return me [6]
and so on.

Comment: Are u asking for a built-in function or just code that will do that.

Comment: question is not clear. if you want to get only the indices where value of a is equal to value of b, _for 2-24, it should just return me 6_ would not return anything, right?

Comment: it can be done using a for loop but will be very slow if the number of values i have are like 100k. I'm looking for a pythonic way to accomplish that

Comment: @silent_warrior I dont want indices where a = b, I want indices for all 'a' where 'b' are equal

Comment: Do you want a list of indices returned or a single value (like the last line)?

Comment: 2-24 ... are those two input arguments of the function you want or is it a subtraction?

Comment: @MichelKeijzers I want indices of all

Comment: What's special about the line with 2-24?  The line before (1-3) is not different when it comes to equality of the values.

Comment: i added an example to make it clear

Comment: So you want [6] returned, not a single value 6, because there can be more values ...also specify the input parameters (including type and semantics).

Comment: the input is the numpy array that contains these two columns 'a' and 'b'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load them in pandas DataFrame and do a groupby:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b})
>>> df.groupby(['a', 'b']).groups
{(1, 1): [0, 1, 2],
 (1, 2): [3],
 (1, 3): [4, 5],
 (2, 24): [6],
 (3, 1): [7, 8, 9, 10],
 (4, 5): [11, 12],
 (4, 7): [13],
 (4, 9): [14]}
```

Then just select out the values you want:

```
>>> df.groupby(['a', 'b']).groups[(1, 1)]
[0, 1, 2]
>>> df.groupby(['a', 'b']).groups[(2, 24)]
[6]
```

Or, if you want, you can get a multiindexed DataFrame using:

```
>>> res = df.groupby(['a', 'b']).apply(lambda group: group.index.values)
>>> res[1, 1]
array([0, 1, 2])
>>> res[2, 24]
array([6])
```

Comment: Whoa!  In case he just wants single inputs, this is wasting computation time and ram ;-)  But I like the approach.

Comment: Actually I want all the values at once. part 1 answers my question, @victor, can you tell me how to convert numpy array to pandas dataframe? im new to pandas. thanks

Comment: @AbhishekThakur Is it a 2d array or you have two 1d arrays?

Comment: @AbhishekThakur If it's a structured 2d array just do `df = pd.DataFrame(your_array)` and pandas will get the column names from the array. If it's a regular 2d array then just pass in the column names: `df = pd.DataFrame(your_array, columns=['a', 'b'])`

Answer (score 1):

To get all indexes where `a[i] != b[i]` try this:

```
return [ i for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] != b[i] ]
```

If you want to create a function which *finds* all indexes where given values of a and b are located, use this:

```
def findIndexes(aValue, bValue):
   return [ i for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] == aValue and b[i] == bValue ]
```

now `findIndexes(2, 24)` will return `[ 6 ]` and `findIndexes(1, 1)` will return `[ 0, 1, 2 ]`.

Comment: actually thats not what i want. please see the edit, with an example

Comment: Edited according to your example.

Answer (score 1):

With use of list comprehension:

```
la = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2 , 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
lb = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 24, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 7, 9]

def find_similar(a, b):
   assert len(la) == len(lb)
   return [s for s in xrange(len(la)) if la[s] == a and lb[s] == b]

print find_similar(1, 1)
print find_similar(2, 24)
```

Prints:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[6]
```

Answer (score 1):

For large NumPy arrays, the quickest way would be to use [np.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np  

a = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4])
b = np.array([1,1,1,2,3,3,24,1,1,1,1,5,5,7,9])

print(np.where((a==1) & (b==1))[0])
# [0 1 2]    
print(np.where((a==1) & (b==2))[0])
# [3]
print(np.where((a==1) & (b==3))[0])
# [4 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using purely numpy and likely a lot faster then the pandas answer.

```
arr
array([[ 1,  1],
       [ 1,  1],
       [ 1,  1],
       [ 1,  2],
       [ 1,  3],
       [ 1,  3],
       [ 2, 24],
       [ 3,  1],
       [ 3,  1],
       [ 3,  1],
       [ 3,  1],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 4,  7],
       [ 4,  9]])

tmp =  np.ascontiguousarray(arr).view(np.dtype((np.void, arr.dtype.itemsize * arr.shape[1])))

uvals,uinds = np.unique(tmp, return_inverse=True)

uinds
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7])

uvals.view(arr.dtype).reshape(uvals.shape + (-1,))
array([[ 1,  1],
       [ 1,  2],
       [ 1,  3],
       [ 2, 24],
       [ 3,  1],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 4,  7],
       [ 4,  9]])
```